# Where can I obtain a sample RETS XML file?

Tags: rets

I don't have an MLS login to retrieve a live RETS XML file, but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to see a sample.  Are there any "sandbox" MLS servers available for non-realtors to test RETS queries against?

I'm fine with it being filled with fake/stand-in data.  Just trying to extrapolate how an actual data-file would look in relation to the DTD files made-available to developers before actually hooking any code up to a live MLS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever looked directly at the XML response returned from RETS since I use a library like [librets](http://nationalassociationofrealtors.github.io/libRETS/) that abstract that away for me so I can just process the data. I found an example of some data see reference document at the end for more info:

```
<RETS ReplyCode="0" ReplyText="">
<COUNT Records="2117">
<DELIMITER value="09"/>
  <COLUMNS>    ListingID   ListPrice </COLUMNS>
  <DATA>    12345678    300000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    23456789    300000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    34567890    300000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    45678901    300000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    56789012    310000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    67890123    310000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    78901234    310000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    89012345    300000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    90123456    350000 </DATA>
  <DATA>    01234567    400000 </DATA>
</RETS>
```

[1] http://www.mredllc.com/%5Crets%5Cdocuments%5CRETS%20Developer%20Start%20Guide1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a violation of all MLS rules to provide any real estate data from their servers to a developer that hasn't been approved to build tools using their data.  You'd need to become a vendor with the MLS and pay the associated fees to get access to the data.

Some MLSs provide the data to you for free to be a vendor, as long as you have an Agent or Broker that will sponsor you in that MLS.  Other MLSs like Northstar in Minneapolis, MRIS / BrightMLS in the DC area charge as much as $1000 a year or more.

It's very important to get a license to use the data since it's copyright.